# Using VBscript restrict layer editing in ArcPad

Tags: layers, arcpad, vbscript, vb

I am attempting to restrict editing on certain layers based on the user log in.

```
Dim objLyr1
Dim objLyr2
Dim objLyr3
Set objLyr1 = Map.Layers("PatchPanel")
Set objLyr2 = Map.Layers("wHydrant")
Set objLyr3 = Map.Layers("ElectricPoles")
If UID = 2 Then
 Msgbox "Electric user. Only enable editing for Electric Users."
 objLyr1.Editable = True
 objLyr2.Editable = False
 objLyr3.Editable = True
ElseIf UID = 4 Then
 Msgbox "Water user. Only enable editing for Water Users."
 objLyr1.Editable = False
 objLyr2.Editable = True
 objLyr3.Editable = False

ElseIf UID = 3 Then
 Msgbox "Sewer user. Only enable editing for Sewer Users."
 objLyr1.Editable = False
 objLyr2.Editable = False
 objLyr3.Editable = False

Else
 Msgbox "Invalid user. Editing Unavailable"
 objLyr1.Editable = False
 objLyr2.Editable = False
 objLyr3.Editable = False
End If
```

This all happens after the log in is verified and the if statement works. The error message I'm getting says "error object required: 'objLyr1' Source Text Unavailable" It is error code 800A01A8.

I'm thinking the Map.Layers command may be generic for instructional documentation and I need to tailor it to my program but that's just a guess.

I'm not sure why and it is a rather vague error.

Does anyone have a clue to why I'm receiving this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was where the script was being called. I moved the user validation if statement on map open. Everything worked as it should have after that change.